# Algorithm to detect if two HTML pages are similar?

Tags: html, ruby, algorithm, web-scraping, similarity

I have 10.000 HTML pages.

I know that some are build with the same CMS systems, and hence has "kind of" the same structure, though not exactly alike. I expect there to be around 100 different CMS's but I don't know them beforehand, so I can't look for predefined patterns.

This is why I need an algorithm to calculate a similarity measure for each page and then cluster them based on similarity..?

I would be happy find some tools in Ruby, but other languages are also welcome.

PS. I do not wan't to look at similarity in content (text). Only wanna do comparison at meta level. Like HTML structure, css rules, class names etc. etc.

Comment: Tough one. If this is a real life problem, you might want to add the recognition patterns yourself. Just open the pages one by one and see if they match any of the patterns you have. If not, analyse the page by hand, find the CMS, and add a pattern to the list. That way, you will eventually have added patterns for every CMS.

Comment: This is real life, and I'm done doing the what you suggest. :-)

Comment: First you have to define what you mean by "similar." Are you trying to see if they have the same structure? That their contents are similar (i.e. same or close to same text)? That they both are discussing the same topic, although their structure and actual content are wildly different? What kind of "similarity" are you aiming for here?

Comment: I'm not talking about text. ONLY meta level info e.g. HTML structure, attribute names css etc.

Comment: You could try to extract the html tags with their attributes with a html parser or a regexp. and then calculate and compare the Levenshtein distance between the extraction.

Answer (score 2):

In a past life I wrote a lot of analytics software for a company that had to dig through a huge number of pages, easily the number you're talking about, to return similar types of information.

No matter how you want to determine similarity, you have to write the rules yourself. Pages vary too much, and code can't really understand what "similar" means, nor can it determine what is important to your particular use.

Things you can do:

- Determine the total size of the "text" nodes (viewable and invisible text plus CSS and JavaScript. You could get the sizes of the last two and subtract that from the overall text size to get an idea of the total content, but that won't take into account the affect CSS or JavaScript has on the visible page.
- Look in meta tags for useful information, like keywords or related pages.
- Look for tables and get counts of their rows and cells and the size of their text, and possibly search for data to correlate or compare.
- Look for links and anchors and get the similarity of their text and/or hrefs.
- Look for images and anything with "alt" text and then compare those.

At the end though, you have to look through the pages and determine what is important and no other programmer can guess what those might be.

HTML structure, the order of the individual tags, isn't nearly as useful as it used to be, since CSS and JavaScript can move things all over the page once it's loaded into a browser, so what the eye sees can vary greatly from what standard code-based tools see. Two versions of the same CMS can have radically different output but, as a result of the CSS/JavaScript, appear the same to viewers, so again, you have to determine how to correlate them.

Comment: Hmm I found this, which seems to produce valid output, in the cases that I have tried and know are "the same", but I don't know how it works, so it's hard to reproduce... http://tool.motoricerca.info/similarity-analyzer.phtml

Comment: Well, as the other comments said, this isn't easy. Too much of what you are trying to do is tied to your particular need. Finding a tool that comes close is nice, but too often, once you push further, you find that the overlap becomes less and less because their needs aren't in-line with yours, and that's when you have to roll your own. Unfortunately, there aren't good canned-solutions for this, but, on the other hand, if there were you might not have the job trying to figure this out, someone else could click a button and it'd magically happen.